# Can a Muslim woman upload pictures of herself for the purpose of working and business purposes?

Tags: halal-haram, women, non-mahram

I've heard from the traditional scholars such as Zakir Naik and Assimal Hakeem saying that it is not permissible nor encouraged for a woman to upload pictures of herself online even if she wears her hijab properly because they say it defeats the purpose of hijab. However, if something of necessity to gain provision(rizq) like working and business, she has to show her face so that the boss or the customers can know her who she is. Like for example, a resume with her face on it so the recruiter can identify her. Otherwise, it will be difficult and users online will assume that she is a bot if she does not show her face.

Not uploading videos or photos of full face makeup tutorial nor showing off the beauty to anonymous audience nor uploading daily life of the woman. Just the photo of the face for familiarity of employers, recruiters and customers. Nothing more than that. Something that is necessary in this modern, fast-paced world.

Comment: In the case of necessity, yes. What those two scholars/sheikhs refer to is in a way of recreation; for fun. But since you have a legitimate reason, it shouldn’t be haram.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the text and description of your question, it is clear that you only want to upload a simple photo with an office use, such as passport photos. With all the emphasis you have on the simplicity of your photo, I must say that uploading it is okay.
As I am familiar with the rulings, I would like to remind you that your photo must meet the following conditions:

```
  1. Be complete with hijab.
  2. The photo was uploaded to introduce you as a real character.
  3. Seeing your photo should not cause corruption and guilt for the viewer.
  4. Take care of your security in cyberspace.
```

This is a security principle and has nothing to do with religion. Every site and blog does not have enough security to get your true face.

https://www.shia-news.com/fa/news/162060/%

https://www.yjc.news/fa/news/6791481/%